# how to get frame of buttons within scrollview?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a scrollview in which 10 buttons have been added.When user clicks any of the button,i have to get the frame of the button exactly in superview perspective,not in scrollview perspective.How can I get it?

Comment: can you put some code plz, i don't really understand what you mean by "perspective".. You want the position of your button from you scrollView, not from your superview, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code.

```
CGRect rect = [scrView convertRect:[btn1 frame] toView:self.view];
```

You will get rect according to your view.